# Is it possible to reflect a java method statically?

Tags: java, reflection

Is there a way to statically reference a method for reflection in Java.  Here's some example code to give you an idea of what I am attempting:

```
public void myFunc(int x) { ... }

public void other() {
    Method m1 = getClass().getMethod("myFunc");  // dynamic
    Method m2 = this.myFunc;                     // static
    Method m3 = MyClass.myFunc;                  // static (alternate)
}
```

I recognize that the above syntax does not work, but I was wondering if there is some sort of syntax similar to this that actually does work.  I want a way to use reflection without worrying about the inherent dangers of referencing a method by a string.

Is there a way to do this, or is it just a pipe-dream?

Comment: pipe-dream. Looks like a C function pointer, but Java does not have this.

Comment: what are `the inherent dangers of referencing a method by a string` ?

Comment: @AlexLynch, runtime linker failures, code injection when the string comes from an untrusted source, hard-to-find bugs because a maintainer fails to find and update all callers of a method, bugs missed because linters and code quality tools (findbugs) get confused by reflective code.

Comment: Do you want the method equivalent of class references like `MyClass.class`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was hoping for.  Unfortunately, it looks like that is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) explains

> this method to compare the birth dates of two Person instances already exists as `Person.compareByAge`. You can invoke this method instead in the body of the lambda expression:
>
> ```
> Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray,
>     (a, b) -> Person.compareByAge(a, b)
> );
> ```
>
> Because this lambda expression invokes an existing method, you can use a > method reference instead of a lambda expression:
>
> ```
> Arrays.sort(rosterAsArray, Person::compareByAge);
> ```

and it goes on to explain the various kinds of method references:

> There are four kinds of method references:

```
Reference to a static method      ContainingClass::staticMethodName

Reference to an instance method
of a particular object            containingObject::instanceMethodName

Reference to an instance method   ContainingType::methodName
of an arbitrary object of a
particular type

Reference to a constructor        ClassName::new
```

---

HISTORICAL NOTE (Written before Java 8 was finalized)

I think the Java closures proposal has something like this.  [Stephen Colebourne](http://blog.joda.org/2007/03/first-class-methods-java-style-closures_3629.html) says:

> Stefan and I are pleased to announce the release of v0.4 of the First-class Methods: Java-style closures proposal.
>
> ## Changes
>
> Since v0.3, we have tried to incorporate some of the feedback received on the various forums. The main changes are as follows:
>
> 1) Constructor and Field literals. It is now possible to create type-safe, compile-time changed instances of `java.lang.reflect.Constructor` and `Field` using FCM syntax:
>
> ```
> // method literal:
> Method m = Integer#valueOf(int);
>
> // constructor literal:
> Constructor<Integer> c = Integer#(int);
>
> // field literal:
> Field f = Integer#MAX_VALUE;
> ```

but I don't think this syntax is available in any shipping JVM.  Closures themselves are definitely not in Java 7.  You might see it in Java 8.

The [Java closures site](http://www.javac.info/) has a pointer to ["Method references"](http://tronicek.blogspot.com/2008/03/method-references-version-2008-03-17.html) which is a bit more up-to-date though it doesn't look like they've changed the syntax much.

Answer (score -3):

[JSR-335](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=335) is what you're looking for. Hopefully it will be available in JDK 8.

Comment: Nope. I think that the question is for litteral acces to methods / fields at compile time. Lambda functions are different.